# ecmascript 6 features found in Chrome 38

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, ecmascript-6

We have an Array with a number of properties on each page. Sometimes it has a "values" property. We examine this with `myArrayObject['values']` and expect either a string or undefined.
After updating to Chrome 38 `myArrayObject['values']` returns `function values() { [native code] }`

After some digging this seems to be related to a [V8 ticket](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3401) to implement [@@unscopables for the 6th Edition of ecmascript](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1908#c2).
These changes were [committed](https://codereview.chromium.org/455743002/diff/1/src/unscopables.js) two months ago. Soon after one dev tried to [roll them back with the note that they were "web-breaking"](https://codereview.chromium.org/455763002/).

So the question is, is Array.values() an undocumented feature, early adoption an ecmascript-6 draft, a bug, or something else? Will this get rolled back? What other upcoming changes should I be aware of?

Small example in Chrome 38.0.2125.101 (on Win7 64):

```
var test=new Array();
// items pushed and popped
...
// test['values'] may have been set at some point
test['values']; //returns a function pointer: function values() { [native code] }.
                // yesterday this returned undefined
```

---

edit: From Bergi's answer this looks like a ES6 feature.

Will there be more ES6 *features* coming out in background patches months before the spec is released? Is there anything I can do to protect our platform? Is there some way to request ES5 compatibility mode?

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript are for numerically indexed collections. If you're using non-numeric property names, you just want a plain object (`{}`).

Comment: @Pointy The object is an array, in addition, it has gained a number of properties. However, this is besides the point. I'll rephrase my question to be more clear.

Comment: What I meant was that there's no reason to use an Array instance in JavaScript to store properties whose names are strings; that is, if you want a "map", you should use an object. It *works*, usually, to use an Array that way, because arrays *are* objects, but it's a questionable practice. For example, if you pass an Array with non-numeric properties to `JSON.stringify()`, you won't get any of those properties in the resulting JSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28514411/104857

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [`Array.prototype.values`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.values) comes from the ES6 Draft. It is a method that returns you an iterator for the values of the array.

If you want to store values in your array that are not numerically indexed, you should not use an `Array` but a plain object (or, in ES6, a `Map`).

Comment: It looks like ES6 is slated to be released summer 2015. Why are users seeing changes now?

Comment: Because ES implementations are experimenting with the proposols, so that people can try them out and give feedback (many features are heavily discussed, and for lots of problems multiple solutions were proposed). Once a feature is mature enough, it will be released from the experimental versions into the public.

Comment: So these changes will be dribbling down slowly as the spec is finalized? Anything I can do to avoid them until we're ready?

Comment: The release date of the spec is when the behavior of features is *settled* - not when they are implemented. It will represent what has been agreed upon by the various involved people. E.g. FF2 had `let` statements back in 2006 - now ES6 will change their semantics a bit, and other implementations will follow up to become compatible (which probably will last some longer time again). The web was always - and will always be - quite diverse :-)

Comment: I don't think you can avoid them. Of course ES6 cares about backwards-compatibility, and about not "breaking the web", but it will not care about old faulty code.

Answer (score 2):

Correction, @@unscopables was never rolled back from V8 -- the second change you link to was merely *prepared* for the case of emergency, but fortunately, we didn't need it, it was never committed. So @@unscopables ships in Chrome 38, and accordingly, so does Array.prototype.values.

There is no way to turn off ES6 features, because doing so would not be very forward-looking, and code relying on it would be doomed to break in a few months or on other browsers anyway.

The ES committee usually is very careful to not "break the web". In practice that means that no *actual* use cases should break, i.e., things that already occur on the web. Strictly speaking, any change breaks some hypothetical code, because even completely new features will observably change the behaviour of 'eval'. If we made avoiding even that a strict criterium then the language could never evolve a iota.

Your specific example doesn't show up in the wild, as far as I can tell. As others have replied, there is no reason to use arrays in this case, []-syntax works just as well with ordinary objects. You only want arrays when your indices are integers specifically.

The only web-breaking issues that previously surfaced with the new Array.prototype.values method had to do with the 'with' construct (which you shouldn't use, ever). Then @@unscopables was introduced to work around that.

***Edit:*** `.values` had to be removed from V8 again, because of a bug in Microsoft's OWA 2013. But consider this a temporary measure. Microsoft is aware of the problem, and `.values` will return as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome 38.0.2125.111 doesn't implement anymore [Array.prototype.values](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.values).

This small test

```
var myArray = new Array();
alert(myArray['values']);
alert(myArray['anotherparameter']);
```

returns `undefined` for both alert.

However the method `hasOwnProperty` can be used to determine if the array has a property called `values` or not:

```
var myArray = new Array();
alert(myArray.hasOwnProperty('values')); // alert false
myArray['values'] = "Hello";
alert(myArray.hasOwnProperty('values')); // alert true
```

this works for browsers implementing `Array.prototype.values` like Opera 25.0.1614.63