# ES6 Array.prototype.values shouldn't it exist by now?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Shouldn't ES6 `Array.protoype.values` exist already by now since this already works:

```
Array.prototype.values = function(){
  return this[Symbol.iterator]();
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let iterator = arr.values();

for(let num of iterator) console.log(num) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: So, your question would be?

Comment: How come it's not already implemented natively without having to the the above

Comment: Which environment you are in?

Comment: Version 42.0.2304.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: Your realization is not correct. You should `return this[Symbol.iterator]` without calling it.

Comment: @alexpods calling `this[Symbol.iterator]()` will return an `ArrayIterator{}` which you then want to return. Try running the code

Comment: @Edwin Oouh, yeah. You're right. Sorry for interruption. I was little confused. I  thought you should write `Array.prototype.values = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`, never mind. By the way, I don't know about v8, but mozilla remove it from SpiderMonkey for [this problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875433). Maybe it'll help you

Comment: Yes it should. Why don't you file a bug? Not sure what the point of a SO question about this is.

Comment: Honestly I have some ideas and stuff that I would like to file, show, present something. and I guess for this file a bug. Yet I have no idea how to do any of that @FelixKling

Answer (score 1):

It breaks too many sites, so it was removed. These are the two relevant issues to keep an eye on:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462936
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875433

There's no ETA as far as I've gathered.

Comment: I should probably close this question, I've already figured out a while back why :)

Comment: @EdwinReynoso Nah, it's still a vlid question. Other people will google and find it.

Comment: Well closing it requires choosing and option that's not "I know the answer" I'll probably answer it myself later