# How to make an iterator out of an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

How would I make an iterator out of an ES6 class in the same manner as JS1.7 `SomeClass.prototype.__iterator__ = function() {...}` syntax?

[EDIT 16:00]

The following works:

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield '1';
        yield '2';
    }

    //*generator() {
    //}

}

an_instance = new SomeClass();
for (let v of an_instance) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

WebStorm flags `*[Symbol.iterator]()` with a 'function name expected' warning directly following the asterix, but otherwise this compiles and runs fine with Traceur.  (Note WebStorm does not generate any errors for `*generator()`.)

Comment: This code works fine for me in node `v8.1.1`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Define a suitable iterator method. For example:

```
class C {
  constructor() { this.a = [] }
  add(x) { this.a.push(x) }
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return this.a.values() }
}
```

Edit: Sample use:

```
let c = new C
c.add(1); c.add(2)
for (let i of c) console.log(i)
```

Comment: And prefix with an asterix to use as a generator function by the looks.

Comment: This particular example is not using a generator. It's simply delegating to an array iterator.

Comment: Could you please add an example of this code being used? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @timkay, done, it's exactly like asked in the question.

Comment: @timkay You probably can't get it to work because arrays [still don't have a `.values()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28514411/1048572) in most implementations. Use `this.a[Symbol.iterator]()` instead

Comment: Thanks! As @bergi points out, most implementations don't support values() for arrays. His solution works more generally. Maybe you could update your code.

Comment: @alexpods answer below is better

Comment: Unlike some of the other answers, this one easily applies to other iterable objects beyond `Array`, such as `Set` and `Map`. It also handles sparse arrays properly.

Answer (score 74):

You need to specify `Symbol.iterator` property for `SomeClass` which returns [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for class instances. Iterator must have `next()` method, witch in turn returns object with `done` and `value` fields. Simplified example:

```
function SomeClass() {
  this._data = [1,2,3,4];
}

SomeClass.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  var index = 0;
  var data  = this._data;

  return {
    next: function() {
      return { value: data[++index], done: !(index in data) }
    }
  };
};
```

Or using ES6 classes and arrow functions:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this._data = [1,2,3,4];
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    var index = -1;
    var data  = this._data;

    return {
      next: () => ({ value: data[++index], done: !(index in data) })
    };
  };
}
```

And usage:

```
var obj = new SomeClass();
for (var i of obj) { console.log(i) }
```

In your updated question you realized class *iterator* through *generator function*. You can do so, but you must understand that iterator COULD NOT BE a generator. Actually iterator in es6 is any object that has specific [`next()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol)

Comment: This actually works, better than the answer flagged as correct. Thanks!

Comment: In order to make the ES5 code work, I had to set `index = -1` like it is in the ES6 code. Possible mistake ?

Comment: @alexpods I just wanted to ask, I noticed your done statement.  When testing this in the console, it never has truth to it.  I was testing it.  It actually would work if it was python, but i was not sure if this is a bug?

Comment: wondering, having this custom iterator, is there an easy way to convert the generated data right into an array? Thinking of adding a method like "toArray" that calls the iterator internally and fills in an array, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: `done: !(index in data)` exits the loop early on sparse arrays. A simple fix is: `done: index == data.length`.  If you need to handle loops that change the array length you can use `>=` and make sure you check `.length` every iteration instead of pre-assigning it to a constant.

Answer (score 28):

Here's an example for iterating over a 2d matrix custom class in ES6

```
class Matrix {
    constructor() {
        this.matrix = [[1, 2, 9],
                       [5, 3, 8],
                       [4, 6, 7]];
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let row of this.matrix) {
            for (let cell of row) {
                yield cell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage of such a class would be

```
let matrix = new Matrix();

for (let cell of matrix) {
    console.log(cell)
}
```

Which would output

```
1
2
9
5
3
8
4
6
7
```

Comment: Note: The above code may need the latest version of nodeJS to work. It compiles fine using `node v8.1.1`

Comment: You can simplify the iterator using `for...of` loops: `for (let row of this.matrix) { for (let cell of row) { yield cell; } }`

Comment: @LukeMWillis - Nice! Much better. Updated answer

Answer (score 19):

Documentation: [Iteration Protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Example class implementing both **iterator protocol** and **iterable protocol** techniques:

```
class MyCollection {
  constructor(elements) {
    if (!Array.isArray(elements))
      throw new Error('Parameter to constructor must be array');

    this.elements = elements;
  }

  // Implement "iterator protocol"
  *iterator() {
    for (let key in this.elements) {
      var value = this.elements[key];
      yield value;
    }
  }

  // Implement "iterable protocol"
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.iterator();
  }
}
```

Access elements using either technique:

```
var myCollection = new MyCollection(['foo', 'bar', 'bah', 'bat']);

// Access elements of the collection using iterable
for (let element of myCollection)
  console.log('element via "iterable": ' + element);

// Access elements of the collection using iterator
var iterator = myCollection.iterator();
while (element = iterator.next().value)
  console.log('element via "iterator": ' + element);
```

Comment: Note to future readers; last loop with _`while`_ doesn't work on it's own without a proceeding `let element;`... well for some JavaScript shells that is. Solid answer otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

### Explanation

Making an object *iterable* means this object has a method named with the `Symbol.iterator`. When this method gets called, it should return an interface called **iterator**.

This **iterator** must have a method `next` that returns the next result. This result should be an object with a `value` property that provides the next value, and a `done` property, which should be `true` when there are no more results and `false` otherwise.

### Implementation

I will also implement an iterator for a class called `Matrix` which all elements will range from `0` to `width * height - 1`. I will create a different class for this iterator called `MatrixIterator`.

```
class Matrix {
    constructor(width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.content = [];

        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                this.content[y * width + x] = y * width + x;
            }
        }
    }

    get(x, y) {
        return this.content[y * this.width + x];
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return new MatrixIterator(this);
    }
}


class MatrixIterator {
    constructor(matrix) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    next() {
        if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

        let value = {
            x: this.x,
            y: this.y,
            value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
        };

        this.x++;

        if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y++;
        }

        return {value, done: false};
    }
}
```

Notice that `Matrix` implements the **iterator** protocol by defining `Symbol.iterator` symbol. Inside this method, an instance of `MatrixIterator` is created which takes `this`, i.e., the `Matrix` instance as parameter, and inside  `MatrixIterator`, the method `next` is defined. I particularly like this way of implementing an iterator because it clearly shows the **iterator** and the implementation of the `Symbol.iterator`.

Alternatively, one can also not define directly `Symbol.iterator`, and instead add a function to `prototype[Symbol.iterator]` as follows:

```
Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    return new MatrixIterator(this);
};
```

### Usage Example

```
let matrix = new Matrix(3, 2);
for (let e of matrix) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Reference - Eloquent Javascript

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone's posted an example of an async iterator, so here you go:

```js
class TableReadStream<T extends any[]> {
    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        let row: T
        while((row = await this.readRow()) !== null) {
            yield row
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
for await(let row of readStream) {
    console.log(row)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of an ES6 iterator class that stores in a sub-object:

```
class Iterator {
    data;

    constructor(data = {}) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    add(key, value) { this.data[key] = value; }

    get(key) { return this.data[key]; }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.data).filter(key => 
        this.data.hasOwnProperty(key));
        const values = keys.map(key => this.data[key]).values();
        return values;
    }
}
```