# Trying to use iterator class by calling for (let x of xy) produces "SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier"

Tags: javascript

If there's any problem with my iterator class I'd love to know.

```
class Group {
  constructor(arr = []){
    this.array = arr;
  }
  add(number) {
    this.array.push(number);
  }
  delete(number){
    this.array = this.array.filter(n => n != number);
  }
  has(number){
    return this.array.includes(number);
  }  
  static from(array){
    return new this(array);
  }
}

class GroupIterator{
    constrctor(group){
        this.x = 0;
        this.group = group;
    }
  next() {
    if (this.x == this.group.array.length) return {done: true};
    var val = this.x
    this.x++;
    return {val, done: false};
}
```

The problem is with the following call:

```
for(let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
// → a
// → b
// → c
```

Comment: `next()` is missing a closing curly-bracket. Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739745/how-to-make-an-iterator-out-of-an-es6-class

Comment: It should probably throw an error saying `group is not iterable` since `Group.from` returns a `Group` object

Answer (score 4):

Because you're calling `Group.from` to create a `Group`, you need `Group` to have a generator that allows for iteration, else you'll get an error that it isn't iterable. Add

```
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
  for (const item of this.array) {
    yield item;
  }
}
```

as a method to `Group` (not to `GroupIterator`):

```js
class Group {
  constructor(arr = []){
    this.array = arr;
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const item of this.array) {
      yield item;
    }
  }
  add(number) {
    this.array.push(number);
  }
  delete(number){
    this.array = this.array.filter(n => n != number);
  }
  has(number){
    return this.array.includes(number);
  }  
  static from(array){
    return new this(array);
  }
}
for(let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
// → a
// → b
// → c
```

Another option, to avoid double `for..of` wrapping, would be to call and return the *array*'s `Symbol.iterator`:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() {
  return this.array[Symbol.iterator]();
}
```

```js
class Group {
  constructor(arr = []){
    this.array = arr;
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.array[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
  add(number) {
    this.array.push(number);
  }
  delete(number){
    this.array = this.array.filter(n => n != number);
  }
  has(number){
    return this.array.includes(number);
  }  
  static from(array){
    return new this(array);
  }
}
for(let value of Group.from(["a", "b", "c"])) {
  console.log(value);
}
// → a
// → b
// → c
```

Comment: and this would be yielded to the Group class? I've never ever seen that form of implementation - can you please explain `[Symbol.iterator]()` a bit more - or explain why this makes the array iterable while it wasn't before?

Comment: `this[Symbol.iterator] = function* () { yield "" }` is this a valid syntax?

Comment: @messerbill `for..of` will look up the `Symbol.iterator` property on the object and call it. In this case, since it's a generator function, everything `yield`ed will be an `item` in the loop. (Another option is to have `Symbol.iterator` *return* an object with a `next` method, somewhat similar to what you're trying to do in `GroupIterator`, but it's a lot more verbose and error-prone) Look up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators