# Mongoose findById returns object but its properties cant be accessed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a property from MongoDB (mongoose) using the `Model.findById()` method. When I `console.log` the response, everything looks fine. But I cannot access it's properties.

```js
//Fetch the conversations
var conversations = await ChatConversation.find({ members: req.token.mid }, 'members is_group').exec();
//Loop through the conversations to and modify each conversation
conversations = await Promise.all(conversations.map(async (conversation) => {
    if(conversation.is_group === false){
        // A conversation contains 2 members, get the user who is not logged in
        var other_id = conversation.members[0] == req.token.mid ? conversation.members[1] : conversation.members[0];
        //Fetch the other participant's details
        var other_participant = await User.findById(other_id, 'name photo');
        
        /*  PROBLEM HERE */
        console.log(other_participant)

        //Assign the newly fetch values
        conversation.name = other_participant.name;
        conversation.picture = other_participant.picture;
    }
    return conversation;
}))
```

This is the code snippet. The log I get is
`{ _id: 60b23d231d6fb73eb43eb5f5, name: 'Ajith Gopi', photo: '' }`

But if I try to access the name property like `other_participant.name` it gives `undefined`

I have tried to get the keys and values of `other_participant`  using `Object.keys(other_participant)` and `Object.values(other_participant)`, I get the following

`Object.keys(other_participant)`:

```
[
  '$__',    'isNew',
  'errors', '$locals',
  '$op',    '_doc',
  '$init'
]
```

`Object.values(other_participant)`:

```
[
  InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: { name: 1, photo: 1 },
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: undefined,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 60b23d231d6fb73eb43eb5f5,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    cachedRequired: {},
    session: undefined,
    '$setCalled': Set(0) {},
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, willInit: true, defaults: true }
  },
  false,
  undefined,
  {},
  null,
  { _id: 60b23d231d6fb73eb43eb5f5, name: 'Ajith Gopi', photo: '' },
  true
]
```

Mongoose Schema:

```js
const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    phone: Number,
    name: String,
    photo: String,
    date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}), 'users');
```

I'm not sure, But I suspect it has something to do with the `Promise.all()`...

NB: I have also tried replacing `findById()` with `findOne()`, And tried adding `exec()` in the end too... Same results

Comment: Hey could you share the database value please it may be because the name is not defined

Comment: @YasharthDubey It's defined, And I'm able to get it when I `console.log` the result (As mentioned in the question). But the object is not accessible when I access using the `other_participant.name`

Comment: oh then wait i am seeing this

Comment: Hey there is also one thing which can cause it which is may be the value is stored in your database but not present in the Schema

Comment: @YasharthDubey I have added my schema too, In the question

Comment: it is my bad sorry.

Comment: @YasharthDubey No, I mean I have added it after you asked :)

Comment: var other_participant = await User.findById(other_id, 'name photo');  change this line to var other_participant = await User.findById(other_id, {name:1,photo:1});

Comment: @YasharthDubey Thanks! But I think I figured it out... I'll add it as answer now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233065/discussion-between-yasharth-dubey-and-ajith-gopi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another solution to get POJO objects from Mongoose [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html): the lean() method

> The lean option tells Mongoose to skip hydrating the result documents.
> This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result
> documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose
> documents.

```
var other_participant = await User.findById(other_id, 'name photo').lean();
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot... I'm making a large scale application and this helped a lot :)

Comment: I have one more question... Why can I access `conversation.is_group` without using lean() or toObject? Is it because I'm iterating through the result and It gives the actual object on every iteration?

Comment: By default, we receive mongoose documents (which is different from Javascript object as you noticed), and all the properties reside in `document._doc`. You can try `conversation._doc.is_group`

Comment: No, I mean.. I'm not using lean() or toObject for my first query (line 2). But on line 5, I'm directly accessing `conversation.is_group` and it's working fine. How might it be working... I wonder o.O

Comment: Suprise moment... I don't know too :))

Comment: Got it... The iterator is overloaded in ES6 class... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739745/how-to-make-an-iterator-out-of-an-es6-class

Answer (score 1):

From the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), I have found out that mongoose findById returns a query object. To access the elements, Either the query has to be converted to a JS object using
`.toObject()`, or the individual properties can be accessed using `.get('PROPERTY_NAME')`.

I have made it

```js
var other_participant = (await User.findById(other_id, 'name photo').exec()).toObject();
```

And now I can directly access the properties.