# Array.values() does not work

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to use `Array.prototype.values()` in my code [as specified by MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) and found that it doesn't work in any code playground. The code I've taken directly from the examples on the MDN.

```js
var arr = ['w', 'y', 'k', 'o', 'p'];
var iterator = arr.values();

for (let letter of iterator) {
  console.log(letter);
}
```

Neither does it work in [repl.it](https://repl.it/@silent_inky/arrayvalues-doesnt-work), nor in MDN's own sandbox.

I thought that this was due to this function being not supported by Node.js for some reason, but I tried the console in both Chrome and Firefox and got the same error. Am I misunderstanding something? Is it a bug?

Comment: Firefox support will start in version 60 and Chrome 66 according to the compatibility table. What version are you using?

Comment: The first thing to check is if it is supported by your playgound

Comment: It's the other way round. Node could support it, FF and Chrome didn't because there were web compatibility problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514411/es6-array-prototype-values-shouldnt-it-exist-by-now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of the browser compatibility table at the bottom of the MDN documentation page, `Array.prototype.values()` won't be supported until Chrome 66 and Firefox 60 - neither of which have been released yet! Interestingly, it *is* currently supported by Safari, and have just verified that myself in the developer tools.

Comment: And as for why something so simple seeming would be lagging so far behind: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/array-prototype-values-compatibility-hazard and https://esdiscuss.org/topic/removing-array-prototype-values

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome Canary is on version 66 right now, and does indeed have support for `Array.prototype.values()`. (I just tested it.)

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur me to look if that version of the browser is released already, should be more attentive in the future.